Movie about a man who arrives in a village and in the village a couple assumed the man was their son
I'm looking for a movie where a man arrives in a village. He is not quite sure who he really is. An old couple in the village assumes that the man is their missing son. The couple had lost their son in the war. They take the man into their home. The other inhabitants of the village are suspicious of the man.
Probably the time of the film is placed after the Second World War. I remember, an Old Movie Theater is an important part of the movie, but I'm not quite sure.
The film is clearly an American. Color movie.

Hahha, I found it!
The Majestic (2001), starring Jim Carrey...

I'm going to guess this is The Majestic (2001) with Jim Carrey

Peter gets drunk and goes for a drive up the coast where he accidentally drives his car off a bridge to avoid an opossum.
He comes to on an ocean beach experiencing amnesia. He is found by Stan Keller who helps him to the nearby town of Lawson, California and the local doctor named Doc Stanton to tend to his wounds. As the town welcomes him, Harry Trimble arrives and believes Peter to be his son Luke who went MIA during World War II nine years ago. Due to his amnesia, Peter accepts himself being treated as Luke by the rest of the town led by Mayor Ernie Cole as Sheriff Cecil Coleman tells Doc to "tell her slowly." Peter warms up to the town including getting to know Harry and Luke's girlfriend Adele Stanton who is Doc's daughter.
Peter adjusts to the new life and helps to renovate the Majestic, a movie theater that had become derelict due to hard times.
Bob Leffert, a veteran of the war that knew Luke, does not believe Peter is Luke and fears Peter may be setting the town up for heartbreak given they had lost sixty other young men during the war. 
Despite this, Peter helps to restore the theater, invigorate the town, and encourages Mayor Cole to display a memorial commissioned by President Franklin D. Roosevelt after the war that the town did not previously have the heart to display.

